# Flutter deep links not working from browser but working with adb command

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking

I'm having the following problem with deep links in flutter.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!--   DeepLinks -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="hordevfree.online" android:pathPrefix="/"/>     
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Working with the command adb

```
  adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    >>     -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    >>     -d "https://hordevfree.online/success"' \com.hordev.porcicultor
```

But when opening the link from another app it does not work and the page opens instead of opening the application

Comment: https://hordevfree.online/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: Can it be the issue that you have two entries for the same bundle id but the different sha256? Have you tried having a same entry and two sha256 values/

Something like this

https://pastebin.com/198Amm7G.

Comment: Hello, yes it is because the one is from playstore. Correct, I already tried just putting local and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: The code you gave me didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried manually verifying the app? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#manual-verification

Please follow this. the assetlinks.json indexing takes some time, you can manually verify.

Comment: Also please try the link sharing in some messaging ( SMS, notes) and click on the link.
I don't think it works if you type the link on the browser directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254742/discussion-between-sailesh-dahal-and-carlos-arevalo).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks?hl=es-419#manual-verification
Following all the steps the command that helped me was the

```
adb shell pm get-app-links <PackageName>
```

With which I could see that my app was being signed with another signature, I don't know the reason. I put that signature in the assetlinks.json file and it works 100%. Regards